# multiphase, define profile

Tags: c++, c, user-defined-functions, fluent

I have a question that I'm stuck in it;

I want to catch the VOF of the phases on the wall by a defined profile. Is there any macro for this purpose, and with what data accessing and looping macro?

I send my code here, so if you can help me, I will be appreciated. but when I apply my code, the fluent crashes out as soon as I initialize the solution.

---

```
DEFINE_PROFILE(heatflux_slip_shoulder_W, t, i)
{
/*Domain *d=Get_Domain(1);*/
int phase_domain_index = 0; /* primary phase index is 0 */
Thread *tm = THREAD_SUPER_THREAD(t);
Thread *subthread = THREAD_SUB_THREAD(tm,phase_domain_index);
double p[ND_ND]; /* this will hold the position vector */
double x, y, r, qslip, sigma, tav_stick, tav_fric, temp, Vx, Vy, Vz, V_W, V_T, VF;
double w = 1120;
double pi = 3.1415927;
double U = 0.002;
double press = 50000000;
double delta = 0.65;
double etta = 0.7;
double heat_ratio = 0.6383;
double Rshol = 0.0075;
double fric ;
double Rpin = 0.0025;
face_t f;
/*thread_loop_f(f, d)*/
{
begin_f_loop(f,t)
{
VF =F_VOF(f,subthread);
F_CENTROID(p, f, t);
x = p[0];
y = p[2];
r = sqrt((x*x) + (y*y));
temp = F_T(f,t);if ((297.<=temp)&&(temp<=273.))
{
sigma_6 = 325.80263157895 + (-0.171052631578952 * temp);
sigma_5 = 282.355263157897 + (-0.0921052631578974*temp);
}
...(and some conditions like above)...

if ((297.<=temp)&&(temp<=855.))
fric = 0.383752244165171 + (-0.000448833034111311 * temp);
else
fric = 0;

tav_6 = sigma_6*1000000/1.732;
tav_5 = sigma_5*1000000/1.732;
tav = VF * tav_6 + (1 - VF ) * tav_5;
qslip = ((pi*w*r/30) - (U*y/r)) * ((etta * (1 - delta) * tav) + (delta * fric * press));

F_PROFILE(f, t, i) = heat_ratio * qslip;
}
end_f_loop(f,t)
}
```

Comment: Your code is inindented, refers to undefined macros, functions and types... you must provide much more context for anyone to make sense of this.

Answer (score 0):

well, here is my code:

```
#include "udf.h"
#include "mem.h"
#include "sg.h"
#include "sg_mphase.h"
#include "flow.h"
#include "metric.h"
DEFINE_PROFILE(heatflux_slip_shoulder_W, t, i)
{
/*Domain *d=Get_Domain(1);*/
int phase_domain_index = 0; /* primary phase index is 0 */
Thread *tm = THREAD_SUPER_THREAD(t);
Thread *subthread = THREAD_SUB_THREAD(tm,phase_domain_index);
double p[ND_ND]; /* this will hold the position vector */
double x, y, r, qslip, sigma, tav_stick, tav_fric, temp, Vx, Vy, Vz, V_W, V_T, VF;
double w = 1120;
double pi = 3.1415927;
double U = 0.002;
double press = 50000000;
double delta = 0.65;
double etta = 0.7;
double heat_ratio = 0.6383;
double Rshol = 0.0075;
double fric ;
double Rpin = 0.0025;
face_t f;
/*thread_loop_f(f, d)*/
{
begin_f_loop(f,t)
{
VF =F_VOF(f,subthread);
F_CENTROID(p, f, t);
x = p[0];
y = p[2];
r = sqrt((x*x) + (y*y));
temp = F_T(f,t);if ((297.<=temp)&&(temp<=273.))
{
sigma_6 = 325.80263157895 + (-0.171052631578952 * temp);
sigma_5 = 282.355263157897 + (-0.0921052631578974*temp);
}
...(and some conditions like above)...

if ((297.<=temp)&&(temp<=855.))
fric = 0.383752244165171 + (-0.000448833034111311 * temp);
else
fric = 0;

tav_6 = sigma_6*1000000/1.732;
tav_5 = sigma_5*1000000/1.732;
tav = VF * tav_6 + (1 - VF ) * tav_5;
qslip = ((pi*w*r/30) - (U*y/r)) * ((etta * (1 - delta) * tav) + (delta * fric * press));

F_PROFILE(f, t, i) = heat_ratio * qslip;
}
end_f_loop(f,t)
}
```